# what is w3 valid url format for files

Tags: html, url, bots

I know standard for accessing file via user is domain_name/file.txt or domain_name/favicon.ico
But server is receiving so many request where there is a trailing / with these links.
some examples

- domain_name/favicon.ico/
- doamin_name/gallery.php/
- domain_name/contact.php/

most of these requests are from Bots. Google Bot, Moz Bot.

update: 
all three links are files not folders.
and links work with or without trailing /
but SEO and Website owners are complaining about duplicate URL issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with these URLs. A client does not care what real-resource is behind these locations. you can create a folder in the webroot called `contact.php`, you can try and put complete garbage in it.

The standard is as follows:

```
scheme://user:password@hostname:port/whatever/here?query-string#hashfragment
```

Comment: Yes I can create a folder contact.php but that folder is not lined anywhere. html and sitemap contains /gallery.php and /contact.php some how bots decided to add / at end.. and server creating error logs.

Comment: @Faraz Many many bots are just guessing URLs and try to hack your server. You should not care about this really, unless the files really exist, just make sure all queried strings are always validated and sanitized.

Comment: I use to ignore these issues but some time ago nibbler forced me to implement 301 redirect so one file can't be accessed with two urls as contact.php is valid file so it has two urls. /contact.php and /contact.php/